# How to Pass all the data from listview in a activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have 2 activities. The first one consist of text view and edit text and a button. Those edit text view and edit text are inside the list view. Text view to populate title from server (I didn't do the populating data from server yet, for now I only make dummy datas) and the edit text is to get data user from user. Once user fill up all the edit text and press the button all the datas from this activity will be passed to another activity. How to make it? for now, i only know the on item click listener at listview, but that's not the one i want. How can i get the datas from listview?

1.Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listview;
ListAdapter adapter;
ViewGroup group1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String[] list = new String[]{
            "TItle 1",
            "TItle 2",
            "TItle 3",
            "TItle 4",
            "TItle 5"
    };

    adapter = new ListAdapter(this,list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    group1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

static class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private String[] textString;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, String[] textString){
        this.context = context;
        this.textString = textString;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return textString.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return textString[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder VH = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, null);

        EditText et1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et1.setTag("et1" + position);


        VH.tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        VH.tv.setText(textString[position]);

        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv;
    }
}
```

2. activity_main.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@+id/btn1">

   </ListView>


   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
   ```
3. activity_retrieve.xml

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="20sp"/>
   ```
4. activity retrieve

   ```
   public class RetrieveActivity extends Activity {

   TextView txtTemp;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve);
       txtTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
   }


   }
   ```

Comment: Quite simple here. Please save the result in the string array then putExtra to new activity

Comment: thanks for the response. How do I get the edit text content within the list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your ListView adapter add an onClickListener() for the button that will be used to start another activity.

First create an ArrayList where the array data will be saved,

```
ArrayList<String> allArray = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder VH = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, null);

        EditText et1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et1.setTag("et1" + position);


        VH.tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        VH.tv.setText(textString[position]);

        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // user has click on the button now get the data from the EditText
            // and pass it to the new Activity

            allArray.add(et1.get(position).toString());
            Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext, RetrieveActivity.class);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("edit_key_name", value);
            StartActivity(i);

            }
        });


        return v;
    }
```

Now from your RetrieveActivity class get the Intent data like this,

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 ArrayList<String> passedText = i.getStringArrayListExtra("edit_key_name");
```

Similarly you can pass data as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get edit text content within the list view in your case:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++){
    EditText editText = (EditText) adapter.getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    //save current text to list by editText.getText()
}
```

After store to a list/array, use putExtra to send to new activity